# Firemokey ComboBox PosSource

Tags: delphi, combobox, firemonkey, livebindings

In Firemonkey by using ComboBoxes I set the displayed item with the following row:

```
ComboBoxSomething.ItemIndex := ComboBoxSomething.Items.IndexOf(VarToStr(Query.FieldValues['fieldname']));
```

There is a BindListLink PosSource binding where the controls ItemIndex+1 binded to the  Bindsource's Recno.

However it works only when I change the Combobox selected text by cliking on it, and does nothing when I set the ItemIndex with the code above.

Do you have any suggestion, what to do different?

Thank you in advance!

Endre

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got it. At the same time I have to set the RecNo of the query as well (Query.Recno := ComboBox.ItemIndex+1;).

But I still don't know, why it isn't set automatically by the livebinding.